# Subir información de TABs en Bootstrap con formularios individuales

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Utilizando Bootstrap, he implementado un TABs con 4 divisiones. En cada división se ingresan datos específicos a través de formularios, uno en cada división.

En el primer TABs, hay varios cuadros input, un textarea, un Dropdown selección simple y un Dropdown selección múltiple.

En el segundo TABs, hay varios cuadros input y dos textarea.

En el tercer TABs, hay una tabla en donde el usuario puede agregar filas en forma dinámica,presionando un botón Agregar.

En el cuarto y último TABs, se suben archivos al servidor a través de un formulario, de modo que cuando se da clic al botón "Subir Archivos", vía Ajax se invoca un php que hace algunas adaptaciones a los nombres de los archivos y los copia en una carpeta del servidor.

Lo que necesito hacer es que el botón "Subir Archivos", realice lo mismo que está haciendo ahora, pero además, después de realizar las validaciones habituales del contenido de los input, tome la información que el usuario ha ingresado en cada uno de los 4 TABs y los grabe en la base de datos y obviamente, suba los archivos seleccionados, cuyos nombres también quedarán en la base de datos, asociados al usuario que está ingresando la solicitud. No sé cómo tomar o hacer referencia a cada uno de los formularios individuales y tomar la información que ingresó el usuario y poder procesarlos de una vez todos, cuando el usuario hace clic en el botón "Subir Archivos".

El código que he implementado es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>YOYO</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnsubir").click(function(){
                var Form=new FormData($("#subedoc")[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"procesar.php",
                    type:"post",
                    data:Form,
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    success: function(data){
                        //alert("Archivos en el servidor");
                        //SE LIMPIA EL INPUT DESPUES DE SUBIR LOS ARCHIVOS
                        $("#selarchivos").val('');
                    }
                });
            });           
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <h1 class="lead-5 text-center justify-content-center py-3 text-white">Creación
    </div>
    <!--CABECERA DE TABS-->
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#fondos" role="tab" aria-controls="fondos" aria-selected="true">
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                        <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>   
                        FONDOS
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#gastos" role="tab" aria-controls="gastos" aria-selected="false">
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                        <i class="far fa-list-alt"></i>   
                        GASTOS
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#adquisiciones" role="tab" aria-controls="adquisicion" aria-selected="false">
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                    <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>   
                        ADQUISICIONES
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>            
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#documentos" role="tab" aria-controls="documentos" aria-selected="false">   
                    <span class="round-tabs two">
                        <i class="fas fa-clone"></i>                        
                        DOCUMENTOS
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <!--TAB UNO-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active mt-2" id="fondos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">       
                <form id="formulariouno">
                    <!--PRIMERA FILA: FECHA, SC Y IDDOC -->
                    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-4 align-self-start">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha"></span>
                                </div>                    
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="sc">S.C. N°</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese número de solicitud" aria-label="sc" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="iddoc">ID DOC</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese número de ID DOC" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <!--SEGUNDA FILA: ANT Y MAT-->
                    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="ant">ANT.</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Antecedente" aria-label="ant" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="mat">MAT.</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Materia" aria-label="mat" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>               
                    </div>
                    <!--TERCERA FILA:  DE: Y A:-->          
                    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha">DE: <?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['unidad']);?></span>
                                </div>                    
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha">A: </span>
                                </div>                    
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <!--CUARTA FILA, TEXTAREA  SOLICITUD-->
                    <div class="container-fluid row mt-1">
                        <div class="col-12 align-self-start">
                            <p>SOLICITUD</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--FILA DE COMBOS TIPO DE COMPRA Y TIPO DE FONDO -->
                    <div class="container row mt-1">
                        <div class="col-3 align-self-start mb-2">
                            <div>
                                <p>TIPO DE COMPRA</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" title="Seleccione tipo Compra">
                                    <option>Contado-1</option>
                                    <option>Contado-2</option>
                                    <option>Contado-3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 align-self-start mb-2">
                            <div>
                                <p>TIPO DE FONDO</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" title="Seleccione el fondo" data-style="btn-info">
                                    <option>FONDO-1</option>
                                    <option>FONDO-2</option>
                                    <option>FONDO-3</option>
                                    <option>FONDO-4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> 
            <!--TAB DOS-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gastos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
                <form id="formulariodos">
                    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-12 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="ant">DESCRIPCIÓN</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Descripción" aria-label="ant" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="col-12 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="mat">ÁREA</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Área" aria-label="mat" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="mat">DIMENSIÓN</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Dimensión" aria-label="mat" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid row mt-1">
                            <div class="col-12 align-self-start">
                                <p>PRÁCTICAS</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="practicas" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="container-fluid row mt-1">
                            <div class="col-12 align-self-start">
                                <p>RESULTADOS</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="resultados" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>               
                    </div>                                                
                </form>            
            </div>

            <!--TAB TRES-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="adquisiciones" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                <form id="formulariotres">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">id Artículo</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Cantidad</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Unid. Medida</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Descripción</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Val.Net.Unit.</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">% Rec. Desp.</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Total</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Eliminar</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <!-- fila base para clonar y agregar al final -->
                                    <tr class="fila-base">
                                        <td scope="row" style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtidarticulo" name="txtidarticulo[]" size="10"/></th>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtcantidad" name="txtcantidad[]" size="3"/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtunidmedida" name="txtunidmedida[]" size="8"/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtdescripcion" name="txtdescripcion[]" size="25"/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtvalnetunid" name="txtvalnetunid[]" size="3"/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txtrecargo" name="txtrecargo[]" size="3" value="0"/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" id="txttotal" name="txttotal[]" size="3" readonly/></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><i class="fas fa-times text-danger eliminar"></i></i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- fin de código: fila base -->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-end">                    
                        <div class="col-3 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">Total Solicitud</span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="ant" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="ttotal" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>                
                    <div class="row justify-content-end">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" id="agregaritem" style="width: 255px">Agregar Item</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="limpiarsolicitud" style="width: 255px">Limpiar Solicitud</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </form>              
            </div>
            <!--TAB CUATRO-->
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="documentos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                <div class="row container-fluid mt-2 justify-content-start">                
                    <div class="col-12 align-self-start">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text text-danger" id="fecha">
                                <h5>Documentos adjuntos.</span>
                            </div>                    
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                                          
                </div>
                <div class="row container-fluid mt-3 justify-content-start">
                    <div class="col-12 align-self-start">

                        <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulariocuatro">     
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-4">
                                <input class="form-control p-1 border" type="file" name="file[]" id="selarchivos" multiple>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info form-control mt-3" id="btnsubir">Subir Archivos</button>
                            </div>                                   
                        </form>                                                                                                                                                                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El PHP es:

```
<?php
session_start();
$carpeta="documentos/";
$files_post=$_FILES['file'];   
$files=array();
$file_count=count($files_post['name']);
$file_keys=array_keys($files_post);
for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
{
    foreach($file_keys as $key)
    {
        $files[$i][$key]=$files_post[$key][$i];
    }
};
print_r($files);
$secuencia=0;
foreach($files as $fileID=>$file)
{
    $secuencia++;
    $fileContent=file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    $nuevonombre=$_SESSION['usuario']."_".$secuencia."_".microtime()."_".$file['name'];
    print_r($nuevonombre);
    file_put_contents($carpeta."/".$nuevonombre,$fileContent);
    /* AQUI SE DEBE COLOCAR LAS SENTENCIAS PARA QUE INSERTE EN LA BD LOS DOCUMENTOS SUBIDOS AL SERVIDOR */
};?>
```

Comment: Sigues necesitando ayuda con esto?

Comment: Así es, he investigado y probado algunas cosas, pero no me resulta.